# How to get xml value to property mediator in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

When I call some service response comes like bellow.

```
<Code>
  <SimpleCode Id="206">
    <Attribute>(1 - 10)</Attribute>
  </SimpleCode>
  <SimpleCode Id="110">
    <StringA>ElementId=HSS1</StringA>
  </SimpleCode>
  <SimpleCode Id="109"/>
</Code>
```

I need to assign each **Id** value to property mediator one by one.Like this,

```
 property_01 --> 216
 property_02 --> 110
 property_03 --> 109
```

Here is how to get Id from response

```
<property expression="$body/Code/SimpleCode/@Id" name="FrameID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

I tried to use for each mediator because this response is dynamic. This Id amount can be change.

Here is my foreach meditor

```
<foreach expression="$body/Error">
   <sequence>
      <sequence key="Gen_ID"/>
   </sequence>
</foreach>
```

Here is Gen_ID Sequense

```
<sequence name="Gen_ID" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property expression="$body/Code/SimpleCode/@Id" name="FrameID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<log description="" level="full">
    <property name="=====FRAME_ID==========" value="=====FRAME_ID=========="/>
    <property expression="get-property('FrameID')" name="===ID VALUE===="/>
</log>
```

When I run this out put is like this,

> 206110109

All Id append to the property> How can I solve this. Thank you

Comment: Could you explain why? Seems to me that if you have a dynamic number of properties you have the same problem when you want to use them as you do not know how many properties exist. If you want to store your ID's for later usage I would say use: <property name="IDs" expression="//Code" type="OM" />

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the description of foreach mediator in [1]. "After mediation, the sub-messages are merged back to their original parent element in the original message sequentially.ForEach does not split the message flow, unlike Iterate Mediator. It guarantees to execute in the same thread until all iterations are complete."

I guess you have to use iterate mediator for your requirement.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ForEach+Mediator